# Unity3D Android Device Suddenly Not Found (Was working before)

Tags: android, debugging, unity-game-engine

I have been making a 2D game using Unity3D and have been debugging it using a Huawei G510-0200 and a Samsung Galaxy S3. Everything was going fine and dandy, I then took a break for a couple of weeks, come back and find that neither of my phones are being found when I try to build the game onto them.

They were building just fine before, so I have NO IDEA what's going on.
Things I have tried:

- USB Debugging is on
- Restarted both devices and my Mac (which is running the Unity3D)
- Reinstalled the SDK
- Retraced my steps and routing the SDK in Unity Preferences
- Updated Drivers
- Tried all the different USB ports.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you see them in the "Devices" view of Android Developer Tools?

Comment: open ADT and open the view "Devices"

Comment: also take a look at this https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/TroubleShooting.html#AndroidTroubleShooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by uninstalling Bluestack's player, which was conflicting with my developer environment, somehow i don't understand what was the issue with blustack's emulator. but surely it was making trouble.

> - Solution: if you have bluestack installed or some other android emulation software then uninstall it.
> - RESTART your system
> - Play the scene in editor with connected to device remote running on it.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the Android section of this: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html

I figured out that debugging via usb is only possible if the device has an IP. I could see the device via `adb devices` command but it wouldn't work in Unity, once it had an IP, everything was just fine.